# Could I use Entity with EF 4 as a template for many tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have many tables with same structure, and every year I add new tables. For example: table012010( id ), table022010( id ) e.t.c. Can I add an Entity to my edmx file and at runtime to change the table name from where to select data or to write data? Is this possible with EF 4?

Comment: If the table structures are the same why do not just add a date column and store them in the same table? Are all the tables from the same database?